# Not getting expected output in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm doing web scraping but i am not getting the output i expected.

I'm learning web scraping and still a beginner. The problem is that not all the quotes are being scraped.

```
import scrapy

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Quotes'
    start_urls = [
    'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        for quotes in response.selector.xpath("//div[@class='quote']"):
            yield{
            'text':quotes.xpath("//span[@class='text']/text()").extract_first(),
            'author':quotes.xpath("//small[@class='author']/text()").extract_first(),
            'tags':quotes.xpath("//div[@class='tags']/child::a/text()").extract(),
            }
```

I am expecting that all the quotes on the first page should be scraped. Instead i get same quote and author again and again but it is extracting all the tags everytime. I am still a beginner. I'll appreciate the help.

Comment: Replace extract_first by extract, this should work.

Comment: It did. But now it is extracted as all the quotes first, than all authors and than all the tags. I want it to be like first quote than author name and after that the tags. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a common mistake when using xpath on nested selectors.

When you use xpath on a selector that you already extracted, if you want to use what you already extracted as the root for the new xpath selector, you need to start the xpath with `.`. If you don't do that, it will just use all the DOM as it normally does.

So just change the final lines to:

```
{
    'text':quotes.xpath(".//span[@class='text']/text()").extract_first(),
    'author':quotes.xpath(".//small[@class='author']/text()").extract_first(),
    'tags':quotes.xpath(".//div[@class='tags']/child::a/text()").extract(),
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot bro it worked. I'll remember it next time.